# How can I use EasyTracker in Android

Tags: android, easytracker

I have a Android project and plan to send data to Google Analytics.

I would like to use EasyTracker and send activity start and stop info. I found just a function like this:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

It works, but in Google Analytics report the package name and I want set custom tag for this.

Can I do this? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358829/google-analytics-custom-screen-names-in-easy-tracker